# PROJ: proj_create: Error 1027 (Invalid value for an argument)

Tags: gdal, proj

I'm doing gdalwarp on a Cygwin platform. The -s_srs was set as:

```
-s_srs +proj=lcc +lat_1=30 +lat_2=35 +lat_0=30 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +a=6370000 +b=6370000 +units=m +no_defs
```

Then I got this error:

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: Error 1027 (Invalid value for an argument): lcc: Invalid value for lat_1 and lat_2: |lat_1 + lat_2| should be > 0
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
+proj=lcc
```

I searched everywhere but don't know why...

Comment: Are you running one of the command-line utilities? The projection definition itself seems fine, but perhaps you need to wrap it in quotes? It could be that it sees everything as separate arguments instead...

Comment: True! It worked with quotes.